# Convert Hex to RGBA

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

My fiddle - http://jsbin.com/pitu/1/edit

I wanted to try an easy hex to rgba conversion. Ever browser I've used renders colors using rgb as default so when using the farbtastic color picker I'm converting the hex value to rgb by grabbing the background color the hex value generates (as rgb by default = simple conversion)

I tried replacing the `)` symbol to `, 1)`, but that didn't work so I went to just see how converting rgb to rgba would work, and I'm still having trouble.

The jquery

```
$('.torgb').val($('#color').css('background-color'));
$('.torgba').val().replace(/rgb/g,"rgba");
```

The goal
[image]

**EDIT**:

[TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) Is a great color manipulation js library that does everything I want here and more. I figure you guys may want to give it a try! - https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor

Comment: [TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) Is a great color manipulation js library that does everything I want here and more. I figure you guys may want to give it a try!

Answer (score 235, accepted):

```
//If you write your own code, remember hex color shortcuts (eg., #fff, #000)

function hexToRgbA(hex){
    var c;
    if(/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)){
        c= hex.substring(1).split('');
        if(c.length== 3){
            c= [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
        }
        c= '0x'+c.join('');
        return 'rgba('+[(c>>16)&255, (c>>8)&255, c&255].join(',')+',1)';
    }
    throw new Error('Bad Hex');
}

hexToRgbA('#fbafff')

/*  returned value: (String)
rgba(251,175,255,1)
*/
```

Comment: very easy to understand solution but it doesn't support 8 form hex like `#ff0000aa`?

Comment: This doesn't work if the input is not exactly 3 or 6 characters.

Comment: @KehlanKrumme What's your example?

Answer (score 151):

@ElDoRado1239 has the right idea, but there's also a cleaner way:

```js
function hexToRGB(hex, alpha) {
    var r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);

    if (alpha) {
        return "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", " + alpha + ")";
    } else {
        return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    }
}

hexToRGB('#FF0000', 0.5);
```

Comment: Note: this will fail on HEX shortcuts, e.g. `#fff`. That should be easily fixable though!

Comment: Well, yes, you have to give the function the correct input…

Comment: Very readable, I like it much more than the reg exp based solution.

Comment: Nice work!! A little thing I have to mention though. I have some bad experience of keeping spaces between comma and the RGBA values in the string. (eg: rgba(255, 35, 234, 0.5)). Especially if you pass this value to another program, be aware of that. Because there some programs which does not accept spaces between values in the string. So, better to remove those spaces from final output.

Comment: `eslint` is just style enforcement. It's only by chance that nothing I wrote contradicts your style preferences. In fact this would not pass linting on the project I'm currently working on, for instance.

Comment: This is brilliant, @AJFarkas, thank you for sharing!

Comment: you don't need that else block (else after return in if) ;) but very nice solution!

Comment: Notice, if alpha is 0, rga is returned. But maybe you want the alpha to be 0. Easy fixable anyway.

Answer (score 56):

ES6 function for only handling 6 character hex with or without the '#':

```
const hex2rgba = (hex, alpha = 1) => {
  const [r, g, b] = hex.match(/\w\w/g).map(x => parseInt(x, 16));
  return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${alpha})`;
};
```

Usage:

```
hex2rgba('#af087b', .5)   // returns: rgba(175,8,123,0.5)
hex2rgba('af087b', .5)    // returns: rgba(175,8,123,0.5)
hex2rgba('af087b')        // returns: rgba(175,8,123,1)
```

Comment: Since `toString` on `Array` joins with `,` and the fact input can be `rrggbbaa hex` you can change it to
    const  rgb = hex.match(...).slice(0,3).map(...)
    returnn\`${rgb},${alpha}\`;

Comment: below code will also convert hex2rgba('#369', 0.5);

var hex2rgba = (hex, alpha = 1) => {
  const [r, g, b] = hex.match(hex.length<=4 ? /\w/g : /\w\w/g).map(x => parseInt(x.length<2?`${x}${x}`: x, 16));
  return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${alpha})`;
};

Comment: I would suggest using `hex.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}/g)` to make sure the input is hex chars only

Answer (score 49):

Clean TypeScript version:

```
hexToRGB(hex: string, alpha: string) {

  const r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);

  if (alpha) {
    return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`;
  }

  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}
```

Based on @AJFarkas's answer.

Comment: This doesn't work everytime in some cases it returns NaN for r, g or/and b.

Comment: Worked out for me! Thx

Comment: shouldn't the else return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})` since it won't have an alpha?

Comment: @AmanshuKataria Yes it should. Good spot.

Comment: No need for `else {}` since you returning in `if`. Also consider one-liner:
`return alpha ? \`rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})\` : \`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})\``

Answer (score 28):

### Any Hex Form Modular Approach

The main challenge is that as of 2018 there are a few forms of HEX. The 6 char traditional form, the 3 char shorten form, and a new 4 and 8 char form that includes alpha. The following function can handle any HEX form.

```js
const isValidHex = (hex) => /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3,4}){1,2}$/.test(hex)

const getChunksFromString = (st, chunkSize) => st.match(new RegExp(`.{${chunkSize}}`, "g"))

const convertHexUnitTo256 = (hexStr) => parseInt(hexStr.repeat(2 / hexStr.length), 16)

const getAlphafloat = (a, alpha) => {
    if (typeof a !== "undefined") {return a / 255}
    if ((typeof alpha != "number") || alpha <0 || alpha >1){
      return 1
    }
    return alpha
}

export const hexToRGBA = (hex, alpha) => {
    if (!isValidHex(hex)) {throw new Error("Invalid HEX")}
    const chunkSize = Math.floor((hex.length - 1) / 3)
    const hexArr = getChunksFromString(hex.slice(1), chunkSize)
    const [r, g, b, a] = hexArr.map(convertHexUnitTo256)
    return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${getAlphafloat(a, alpha)})`
}
```

Alpha could be provided to the function in the following ways:

1. As part of a 4, or 8 form HEX .
2. As a second parameter between 0-1,

**OutPut**

```js
    const c1 = "#f80"
    const c2 = "#f808"
    const c3 = "#0088ff"
    const c4 = "#0088ff88"
    const c5 = "#98736"

    console.log(hexToRGBA(c1))   //  rgba(255, 136, 0, 1)
    console.log(hexToRGBA(c2))   //  rgba(255, 136, 0, 0.53125)
    console.log(hexToRGBA(c3))   //  rgba(0, 136, 255, 1)
    console.log(hexToRGBA(c4))   //  rgba(0, 136, 255, 0.53125)
    console.log(hexToRGBA(c5))   //  Uncaught Error: Invalid HEX

    console.log(hexToRGBA(c1, 0.5))   //  rgba(255, 136, 0, 0.5)
    console.log(hexToRGBA(c3, 0.5))   //  rgba(0, 136, 255, 0.5)
```

Comment: Some browsers support Hex colours with opacity, other do not. This answer was very useful in converting 8 form hex to rgba, rgba being supported in all browsers.

Comment: @George, Thanks! After creating this I asked myself if such a comprehensive approach is actually necessary. Your feedback is valuable.

Comment: I think there might be 1 tiny bug in the alpha calc. I think it should read: return a / 255 otherwise FF doesn't return 1

Comment: @DustinKerstein nice catch! Probably can't do harm, but still should be fixed.

Comment: This is the best answer and it worked for me with all unit tests.

Answer (score 12):

Pure JS solution if it helps:

```
function hexToRGB(hex,alphaYes){
 var h = "0123456789ABCDEF";
 var r = h.indexOf(hex[1])*16+h.indexOf(hex[2]);
 var g = h.indexOf(hex[3])*16+h.indexOf(hex[4]);
 var b = h.indexOf(hex[5])*16+h.indexOf(hex[6]);
 if(alphaYes) return "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", 1)";
 else return "rgb("+r+", "+g+", "+b+")";
}
```

"alphaYes" is "true" or "false" depending upon whether you want the alpha or not.

[image: Preview]

Comment: The `else` keyword is unnecessary in this case. It will return the non-alpha regardless.

Comment: Oh, yeah, but this seems more "tidy" to me. Just a matter of personal preference I guess.

Comment: This code doesn't work with lowercase hex (eg. `#f0a16e`). I suggest to convert `hex` with `toUpperCase` first.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a function that returns rgb or rgba if you provide an alpha. The function also converts short hex color codes too.

**function:**

```
function hexToRgb(hex, alpha) {
   hex   = hex.replace('#', '');
   var r = parseInt(hex.length == 3 ? hex.slice(0, 1).repeat(2) : hex.slice(0, 2), 16);
   var g = parseInt(hex.length == 3 ? hex.slice(1, 2).repeat(2) : hex.slice(2, 4), 16);
   var b = parseInt(hex.length == 3 ? hex.slice(2, 3).repeat(2) : hex.slice(4, 6), 16);
   if ( alpha ) {
      return 'rgba(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ', ' + alpha + ')';
   }
   else {
      return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
   }
}
```

**examples:**

```
hexToRgb('FF0000');// rgb(255, 0, 0)
hexToRgb('#FF0000');// rgb(255, 0, 0)
hexToRgb('#FF0000', 1);// rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)
hexToRgb('F00');// rgb(255, 0, 0)
hexToRgb('#F00');// rgb(255, 0, 0)
hexToRgb('#F00', 1);// rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 9):

**ES6** modern, RegEx free, solution with error checking and constant arrow function, that returns null for errors. If alpha is not given then the default value of one is used:

```
const hexToRGB = (hex, alpha = 1) => {
    let parseString = hex;
    if (hex.startsWith('#')) {parseString = hex.slice(1, 7);}
    if (parseString.length !== 6) {return null;}
    const r = parseInt(parseString.slice(0, 2), 16);
    const g = parseInt(parseString.slice(2, 4), 16);
    const b = parseInt(parseString.slice(4, 6), 16);
    if (isNaN(r) || isNaN(g) || isNaN(b)) {return null;}
    return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`;
};
```

Note: It returns `null` for errors. You may replace `{return null;}` with a throw statement: `{throw "Not a valid hex color!";}`, but then you should call it from within 
`try-catch`:

```
hexToRGB("#3454r5") => null
hexToRGB("#345465") => rgba(52, 84, 101, 1)
hexToRGB("#345465", 0.5) => rgba(52, 84, 101, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 5):

I liked the @AJFarkas answer and append the support for shortcut hex (#fff) to it

```js
function hexToRGB(hex, alpha) {
    if (!hex || [4, 7].indexOf(hex.length) === -1) {
        return; // throw new Error('Bad Hex');
    }

    hex = hex.substr(1);
    // if shortcuts (#F00) -> set to normal (#FF0000)
    if (hex.length === 3) { 
        hex = hex.split('').map(function(el){ 
              return el + el + '';
            }).join('');
    }

    var r = parseInt(hex.slice(0, 2), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.slice(2, 4), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.slice(4, 6), 16);

    if (alpha !== undefined) {
        return "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", " + alpha + ")";
    } else {
        return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    }
}

document.write(hexToRGB('#FF0000', 0.5));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(hexToRGB('#F00', 0.4));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick function that supports 3, 4, 6 and 8 character color codes:

```
function hexToRGBA(hex) {
    // remove invalid characters
    hex = hex.replace(/[^0-9a-fA-F]/g, '');

    if (hex.length < 5) { 
        // 3, 4 characters double-up
        hex = hex.split('').map(s => s + s).join('');
    }

    // parse pairs of two
    let rgba = hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(s => parseInt(s, 16));

    // alpha code between 0 & 1 / default 1
    rgba[3] = rgba.length > 3 ? parseFloat(rgba[3] / 255).toFixed(2): 1;

    return 'rgba(' + rgba.join(', ') + ')';
}
```

Here's what it does. It removes any non-hexadecimal characters. If the HEX is shorter than 5 (3 or 4) characters, it doubles each character. It then splits the HEX into pairs of two characters and parses each pair to an integer. If there is an alpha HEX, it's parsed to a float from 0 to 1, otherwise it's defaulted to 1. The RGBA string is then formed by joining the array and returned.

Answer (score 4):

A clean and readable typescript way: (I could separate type, but it's easier to copy past like that)

```js
export const hexToRGB = (hex: string, alpha: number | undefined = 1) => {
  hex = hex.toUpperCase();

  const r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);

  return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ES2015+ version that's a little more defensive and handles the shorthand 3-digit syntax.

```
/*
 * Takes a 3 or 6-digit hex color code, and an optional 0-255 numeric alpha value
 */
function hexToRGB(hex, alpha) {
  if (typeof hex !== 'string' || hex[0] !== '#') return null; // or return 'transparent'

  const stringValues = (hex.length === 4)
        ? [hex.slice(1, 2), hex.slice(2, 3), hex.slice(3, 4)].map(n => `${n}${n}`)
        : [hex.slice(1, 3), hex.slice(3, 5), hex.slice(5, 7)];
  const intValues = stringValues.map(n => parseInt(n, 16));

  return (typeof alpha === 'number')
    ? `rgba(${intValues.join(', ')}, ${alpha})`
    : `rgb(${intValues.join(', ')})`;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function hexToRGB(hex, alpha) {
    var r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);

    if (alpha) {
        return "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", " + alpha + ")";
    } else {
        return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    }
}

hexToRGB('#FF0000', 0.5);
```

Comment: Simple and short, thanks! For a 1-liner and to return the result as array (assuming no alpha is needed, like in my case), this can be used: `return [parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16), parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16), parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16)];`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I like to use ES6 methods alongside preventing myself to using RegExp, RegExp is not safe, I don't trust it, the below answer is TypeScript, if you only need JavaScript just remove types:

```js
// TypeScript

const hex2rgba = (hex: string, alpha = 1): string => {
  if (alpha > 1 || alpha < 0) {
    throw new Error('alpha is not correct!');
  }

  const red = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const green = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const blue = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);

  return `rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${alpha})`;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After so many years, just for the record, the DOM API does this convertion by default including the alpha. I mean if you do like;

```
tempElement.style.cssText = "color: #de1e7eaa";
console.log(tempElement.style.color) // <- rgb(222, 30, 126, 0.667)
```

you get RGB values as a string. Then you may or not process it according to your needs. We can leverage this opportunity if we are lazy enough.

```js
var color = "#de1e7eaa",                 // hex color code in string including alpha
    temp  = document.createElement("i"), // just a temporary element
    rgbStr,
    rgbInt;
temp.style.cssText = `color: ${color}`;  // assign it to the style of the <i> element
rgbStr = temp.style.color;
rgbInt = Array.from(rgbStr.matchAll(/\d+\.?\d*/g), c=> +c[0]) // temp.style.color gives RGB string
                                                              // then we convert it to Number if need be
console.log(rgbStr);
console.log(rgbInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

And another one based around bit shifting.

```
// hex can be a string in the format of "fc9a04", "0xfc9a04" or "#fc90a4" (uppercase digits are allowed) or the equivalent number
// alpha should be 0-1
const hex2rgb = (hex, alpha) => {
  const c = typeof(hex) === 'string' ? parseInt(hex.replace('#', ''), 16)  : hex;
  return `rgb(${c >> 16}, ${(c & 0xff00) >> 8}, ${c & 0xff}, ${alpha})`;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let hex2rgba= (hex,a)=> `rgba(${hex.substr(1).match(/../g).map(x=>+`0x${x}`)},${a})`
```

```js
/// hex - str e.g. "#abcdef"; a - alpha range 0-1; result e.g. "rgba(1,1,1,0)"
let hex2rgba= (hex,a)=> `rgba(${hex.substr(1).match(/../g).map(x=>+`0x${x}`)},${a})`;

function convert() {
  console.log(hex2rgba(inp.value,1));
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="#abcdef" >
<button onclick="convert()">convert</button>
```

Comment: you need to update rgb to rgba in the return 

Comment: @AlexanderCherednichenko you are right - thank you - fixed

Answer (score 1):

### Works with all shortcuts

Based on [@kennebec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646738/convert-hex-to-rgba/21648508#21648508)'s answer, here is a solution which works with all hex shortcuts (#123, #1234, #123456, #12345678).

```js
const hex2rgba = (hex) => {
    let c = hex.substring(1).split('');

    if (!/^#(([\dA-Fa-f]{3}){1,2}|([\dA-Fa-f]{4}){1,2})$/.test(hex)) {
        throw new Error('Your hexadecimal color is not correct.');
    }

    switch (c.length) {
        case 3:
            c = [c[0] + c[0], c[1] + c[1], c[2] + c[2], 'ff'];
            break;
        case 4:
            c = [c[0]+c[0], c[1]+c[1], c[2]+c[2], c[3]+c[3]];
            break;
        case 6:
            c = [c[0]+c[1], c[2]+c[3], c[4]+c[5], 'ff'];
            break;
        case 8:
            c = [c[0]+c[1], c[2]+c[3], c[4]+c[5], c[6]+c[7]];
            break;
    }

    c = c.map((char) => parseInt(char, 16).toString());
    c[3] = (Math.round((parseInt(c[3],10)/255)*100)/100).toString();
    return c[3] === '1'
        ? `rgb( ${c[0]}, ${c[1]}, ${c[2]})`
        : `rgba(${c[0]}, ${c[1]}, ${c[2]}, ${c[3]})`;
}

//return a rgb or rgba value according to the alpha value
console.log(hex2rgba('#af6'))
console.log(hex2rgba('#af6f'))
console.log(hex2rgba('#af64f576'))
```

### Typescript Version

```js
const hex2rgba = (hex: string): string => {
    let c: string[] = hex.substring(1).split('');

    if (!/^#(([\dA-Fa-f]{3}){1,2}|([\dA-Fa-f]{4}){1,2})$/.test(hex)) {
        throw new Error('Your hexadecimal color is not correct.');
    }

    switch (c.length) {
        case 3:
            c = [c[0] + c[0], c[1] + c[1], c[2] + c[2], 'ff'];
            break;
        case 4:
            c = [c[0]+c[0], c[1]+c[1], c[2]+c[2], c[3]+c[3]];
            break;
        case 6:
            c = [c[0]+c[1], c[2]+c[3], c[4]+c[5], 'ff'];
            break;
        case 8:
            c = [c[0]+c[1], c[2]+c[3], c[4]+c[5], c[6]+c[7]];
            break;
    }

    c = c.map((char) => parseInt(char, 16).toString());
    c[3] = (Math.round((parseInt(c[3],10)/255)*100)/100).toString();
    return c[3] === '1'
        ? `rgb( ${c[0]}, ${c[1]}, ${c[2]})`
        : `rgba(${c[0]}, ${c[1]}, ${c[2]}, ${c[3]})`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely overkill for most use cases, but if you need a solution that **handles every edge case** including all named colors, and actually converts *any valid CSS color string* (not just hex) to RGBA:

```js
function toRGBA(cssColor) {
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.color = cssColor;
  el.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  let rgba = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("color");
  el.remove();
  let [r, g, b, a] = rgba.match(/[0-9.]+/g).map(n => Number(n));
  if(a === undefined) a = 1; // <-- getPropertyValue returns rgb(...) if there is no transparency, so we add alpha if missing
  return [r, g, b, a];
}
```

```js
toRGBA("#34f1a8") // [52, 241, 168, 1]
toRGBA("#fe6") // [255, 238, 102, 1]
toRGBA("blue") // [0, 0, 255, 1]
toRGBA("hsl(0, 90%, 50%)") // [242, 13, 13, 1]
...
```

(Obviously this approach is not appropriate for server-side code like Deno or Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

Convert HEX with alpha (ahex) in to rgba.

```
function ahex_to_rba(ahex) {
    //clean #
    ahex = ahex.substring(1, ahex.length);
    ahex = ahex.split('');

    var r = ahex[0] + ahex[0],
        g = ahex[1] + ahex[1],
        b = ahex[2] + ahex[2],
        a = ahex[3] + ahex[3];

    if (ahex.length >= 6) {
        r = ahex[0] + ahex[1];
        g = ahex[2] + ahex[3];
        b = ahex[4] + ahex[5];
        a = ahex[6] + (ahex[7] ? ahex[7] : ahex[6]);
    }

    var int_r = parseInt(r, 16),
        int_g = parseInt(g, 16),
        int_b = parseInt(b, 16),
        int_a = parseInt(a, 16);


    int_a = int_a / 255;

    if (int_a < 1 && int_a > 0) int_a = int_a.toFixed(2);

    if (int_a || int_a === 0)
        return 'rgba('+int_r+', '+int_g+', '+int_b+', '+int_a+')';
    return 'rgb('+int_r+', '+int_g+', '+int_b+')';
}
```

Try it yourself with snippet:

```js
function ahex_to_rba(ahex) {
    //clean #
    ahex = ahex.substring(1, ahex.length);
    ahex = ahex.split('');

    var r = ahex[0] + ahex[0],
        g = ahex[1] + ahex[1],
        b = ahex[2] + ahex[2],
        a = ahex[3] + ahex[3];

    if (ahex.length >= 6) {
        r = ahex[0] + ahex[1];
        g = ahex[2] + ahex[3];
        b = ahex[4] + ahex[5];
        a = ahex[6] + (ahex[7] ? ahex[7] : ahex[6]);
    }

    var int_r = parseInt(r, 16),
        int_g = parseInt(g, 16),
        int_b = parseInt(b, 16),
        int_a = parseInt(a, 16);


    int_a = int_a / 255;

    if (int_a < 1 && int_a > 0) int_a = int_a.toFixed(2);

    if (int_a || int_a === 0)
        return 'rgba('+int_r+', '+int_g+', '+int_b+', '+int_a+')';
    return 'rgb('+int_r+', '+int_g+', '+int_b+')';
}


$(function() {
  $('#go').click(function() {
    $('p b').text(ahex_to_rba($('#hex').val()));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hex" type="text" value="#ffaaffaa">
<input id="go" type="button" value="Go">

<p>Result: <b></b></p>
```

[Original Author](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ahex)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ElDoRado1239

For those that want to pass alpha value (typescript snippet):

```
static hexToRGB(hex: string, alpha: number): string {
    var h = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var r = h.indexOf(hex[1]) * 16 + h.indexOf(hex[2]);
    var g = h.indexOf(hex[3]) * 16 + h.indexOf(hex[4]);
    var b = h.indexOf(hex[5]) * 16 + h.indexOf(hex[6]);
    if (alpha) {
      return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`
    }

    return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [@kennebec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646738/convert-hex-to-rgba/21648508#21648508)'s solution to have `alpha` parameter

```
function hexToRgbA(hex, alpha=1){
    if(alpha > 1) alpha = 1;
    if(alpha < 0) alpha = 0;
    var c;
    if(/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)){
        c= hex.substring(1).split('');
        if(c.length== 3){
            c= [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
        }
        c= '0x'+c.join('');
        return 'rgba('+[(c>>16)&255, (c>>8)&255, c&255].join(',')+','+alpha+')';
    }
    throw new Error('Bad Hex');
}

hexToRgbA('#fce881', 0.6);

/* returned value: (String)
rgba(252,232,129,0.6)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all use cases
(short codes, long codes, with/without alpha)

```
hexToRGBA=q=>{
  q=q.replace('#', '')
  let l=q.length
  if(l!=3 && l!=4 && l!==6 && l!=8) return
  let red, green, blue, alpha, red_, green_, blue_, alpha_
  switch(l){
    case 3:
      red_     = q[0]+q[0]
      green_   = q[1]+q[1]
      blue_    = q[2]+q[2]
      alpha    = 255
    break
    case 4:
      red_     = q[0]+q[0]
      green_   = q[1]+q[1]
      blue_    = q[2]+q[2]
      alpha_   = q[3]+q[3]
      alpha    = +("0x"+alpha_)
    break
    case 6:
      red_     = q[0]+q[1]
      green_   = q[2]+q[3]
      blue_    = q[4]+q[5]
      alpha    = 255
    break
    case 8:
      red_     = q[0]+q[1]
      green_   = q[2]+q[3]
      blue_    = q[4]+q[5]
      alpha_   = q[6]+q[7]
      alpha    = +("0x"+alpha_)
    break
  }
  red    = +("0x"+red_)
  green  = +("0x"+green_)
  blue   = +("0x"+blue_)
  return [red, green, blue, alpha]
}
```

note: alpha is returned as the 4th element, range 0-255

Answer (score 0):

```
function* chunks(array, size) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += size) {
        yield array.slice(i, i + size);
    }
}

function hexToRgba(hex, opacity = 1) {
    const arr = hex.replace("#", "").split("");

    return [...chunks(arr, arr.length === 6 ? 2 : 1)].reduce(
        (accum, cv, index, array) => {
            const lastIndex = array.length - 1 === index;
            const int = parseInt(
                array.length === 2 ? cv.join("") : cv[0] + cv[0],
                16
            );

            return accum + int + (lastIndex ? `,${opacity})` : ",");
        },
        "rgba("
    );
}

console.log(hexToRgba("#eee", 1));
```

With a generator and reduce. Can be used with or without a `#`.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner if you only need to handle the simple case (i.e. doesn't handle shortcuts like `#fff`):

```js
"aabbcc".split(/(..)/).filter(c=>c).map(c => parseInt(c, 16))
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to re-implement the wheel:

- RGB to HEX: https://github.com/sindresorhus/rgb-hex
- HEX to RGB: https://github.com/sindresorhus/hex-rgb

Comment: sometimes redesigning a wheel gives you a smoother ride...

Comment: that's what wheel designers would say.. :D

Comment: No need to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut...

Answer (score -1):

I'm just gonna put this right here:

```js
(str, alpha) => {


    if(!/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(str))
      throw new Error('Bad hex')


    let c = str.substring(1).split('')
    if(c.length === 3) c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
    c = '0x'+c.join('');
    return `rgba(${(c>>16)&255}, ${(c>>8)&255}, ${c&255}, ${alpha})`;

};
```

Answer (score -11):

Try This

```
<div class="torgb" onclick="rgba();" style="background-color:#000; width:20px; height:20px;"></div>
<script>
function rgba(){
$('.torgb').attr('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,1)');
$('.torgb').attr('onclick','hex();');
}
function hex(){
$('.torgb').attr('background-color','#000');
$('.torgb').attr('onclick','rgba();');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are the `hex` and `rgba` functions coming from?