# How to set background color of view transparent in React Native

Tags: react-native

This is the style of the view that i have used

```js
backCover: {
  position: 'absolute',
  marginTop: 20,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
}
```

Currently it has a white background. I can change the backgroundColor as i want like `'#343434'` but it accepts only max 6 hexvalue for color so I cannot give opacity on that like `'#00ffffff'`. I tried using opacity like this

```js
backCover: {
  position: 'absolute',
  marginTop: 20,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  opacity: 0.5,
}
```

but it reduces visibility of view's content.
So any answers?

Answer (score 499, accepted):

### Use `rgba` value for the `backgroundColor`.

For example,

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)'
```

This sets it to a grey color with 80% opacity, which is derived from the opacity decimal, `0.8`. This value can be anything from `0.0` to `1.0`.

Comment: why on earth are color vals 8 bit and alpha vals floats?

Comment: @duhaime, not sure why specifically, but 8-bits makes sense from a memory sense (especially historically). Alpha values make more sense to have 0 and 1 as min and max for fully transparent or fully opaque. For example, if you wanted something to be 25% transparent, you don't want to figure out what 1/4th of 255 is.

Comment: 8 bits because rgb values range from 0 to 255 each i.e. 256 values. 8 bits can represent 2^8 = 256 values. Bingo!

Answer (score 163):

The following works fine:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, alpha)'
```

You could also try:

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

Comment: backgroundColor: 'transparent' is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 46):

Try this `backgroundColor: '#00000000'`
it will set background color to transparent, it follows #rrggbbaa hex codes

Comment: For some reason, this variant displays the result color with opacity incorrectly. If I'm not mistaken it's a bug in RN. Therefore better to use the `rgba` way.

Comment: @ShyngysKassymov https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4 check this

Comment: @O.o interesting, that makes sense. Thanks for pointing out! But IMO it's easier to use the `rgba` way :)

Comment: does it mean that the format should be #aarrggbb instead?

Comment: I meant you can use the hexavalue in `rrggbbaa`.

Comment: For example, `#000000E6` is 90% opacity. @ShyngysKassymov

Answer (score 18):

Surprisingly no one told about this, which provides some !clarity:

```
style={{
backgroundColor: 'white',
opacity: 0.7
}}
```

Comment: This solution defines opacity to entire view, not just its background, resulting all its children to become semi-opaque as well (that is actually pointed out in original question)

Comment: It's for entire view. even it will blur the text as well.

Comment: NB: Just to give you an idea, even though the score is 20 it got like 40 upvotes and 20 downvotes. I know this is not the perfect solution for this question as pointed by @CoolSoft but somehow it has also helped many people.

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware of the current conflicts that exists with iOS and RGBA backgrounds.

> Summary: public React Native currently exposes the iOS layer shadow
>   properties more-or-less directly, however there are a number of
>   problems with this:
>
> 1) Performance when using these properties is poor by default. That's
>   because iOS calculates the shadow by getting the exact pixel mask of
>   the view, including any tranlucent content, and all of its subviews,
>   which is very CPU and GPU-intensive. 2) The iOS shadow properties do
>   not match the syntax or semantics of the CSS box-shadow standard, and
>   are unlikely to be possible to implement on Android. 3) We don't
>   expose the `layer.shadowPath` property, which is crucial to getting
>   good performance out of layer shadows.
>
> This diff solves problem number 1) by implementing a default
>   `shadowPath` that matches the view border for views with an opaque
>   background. This improves the performance of shadows by optimizing for
>   the common usage case. I've also reinstated background color
>   propagation for views which have shadow props - this should help
>   ensure that this best-case scenario occurs more often.
>
> For views with an explicit transparent background, the shadow will
>   continue to work as it did before ( `shadowPath` will be left unset,
>   and the shadow will be derived exactly from the pixels of the view and
>   its subviews). This is the worst-case path for performance, however,
>   so you should avoid it unless absolutely necessary. **Support for this
>   may be disabled by default in future, or dropped altogether.**
>
> For translucent images, it is suggested that you bake the shadow into
>   the image itself, or use another mechanism to pre-generate the shadow.
>   For text shadows, you should use the textShadow properties, which work
>   cross-platform and have much better performance.
>
> Problem number 2) will be solved in a future diff, possibly by
>   renaming the iOS shadowXXX properties to boxShadowXXX, and changing
>   the syntax and semantics to match the CSS standards.
>
> Problem number 3) is now mostly moot, since we generate the shadowPath
>   automatically. In future, we may provide an iOS-specific prop to set
>   the path explicitly if there's a demand for more precise control of
>   the shadow.
>
> Reviewed By: weicool

Commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e4c53c28aea7e067e48f5c8c0100c7cafc031b06

Answer (score 5):

Try to use transparent attribute value for making transparent background color.

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding reference of React-Native Version 0.64

### Named colors

- [Named Colors: DOCS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/colors#named-colors)

> In React Native you can also use color name strings as values.
> Note: React Native only supports lowercase color names. Uppercase color names are not supported.
> transparent#
> This is a shortcut for rgba(0,0,0,0), same like in CSS3.

Hence you can do this:

```js
background: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'        
},
```

Which is a shortcut of :

```js
background: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'            
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you have hex color, you can convert it to rgba and set the opacity there:

```
const hexToRgbA = (hex, opacity) => {
  let c;
  if (/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)) {
    c = hex.substring(1).split('');
    if (c.length === 3) {
      c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
    }
    c = `0x${c.join('')}`;
    return `rgba(${[(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',')},${opacity})`;
  }
  throw new Error('Bad Hex');
};

const color = '#1f8b7f'; // could be a variable

return (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: hexToRgbA(color, 0.1) }} />
)
```

[source that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648508/5757635)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use background is hex code #rrggbbaa but it should be in hex.
Eg: 50% opacity means 256/2 =128, then convert that value(128) in HEX that will be 80,use `#00000080` 80 here means 50% transparent.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick help you,

Add one View element and add style as below to that view

```
    .opaque{
       position:'absolute',
       backgroundColor: 'black',
       opacity: 0.7,
       zIndex:0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this work for me

```
'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is my solution to a modal that can be rendered on any screen and initialized in App.tsx

ModalComponent.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import EventEmitter from 'events';
// I keep localization files for strings and device metrics like height and width which are used for styling 
import strings from '../../config/strings';
import metrics from '../../config/metrics';

const emitter = new EventEmitter();
export const _modalEmitter = emitter

export class ModalView extends Component {
    state: {
        modalVisible: boolean,
        text: string, 
        callbackSubmit: any, 
        callbackCancel: any,
        animation: any
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            text: "", 
            callbackSubmit: (() => {}), 
            callbackCancel: (() => {}),
            animation: new Animated.Value(0)
        } 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        _modalEmitter.addListener(strings.modalOpen, (event) => {
            var state = {
                modalVisible: true,
                text: event.text, 
                callbackSubmit: event.onSubmit, 
                callbackCancel: event.onClose,
                animation: new Animated.Value(0)
            } 
            this.setState(state)
        })
        _modalEmitter.addListener(strings.modalClose, (event) => {
            var state = {
                modalVisible: false,
                text: "", 
                callbackSubmit: (() => {}), 
                callbackCancel: (() => {}),
                animation: new Animated.Value(0)
            } 
            this.setState(state)
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        var state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            text: "", 
            callbackSubmit: (() => {}), 
            callbackCancel: (() => {})
        } 
        this.setState(state)
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        _modalEmitter.emit(strings.modalClose)
    }

    startAnimation=()=>{
        Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
            toValue : 0.5,
            duration : 500
        }).start()
    }

    body = () => {
        const animatedOpacity ={
            opacity : this.state.animation
        }
        this.startAnimation()
        return (
            <View style={{ height: 0 }}>
                <Modal
                    animationType="fade"
                    transparent={true}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}>

                    // render a transparent gray background over the whole screen and animate it to fade in, touchable opacity to close modal on click out

                    <Animated.View style={[styles.modalBackground, animatedOpacity]} > 
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.closeModal()} activeOpacity={1} style={[styles.modalBackground, {opacity: 1} ]} > 
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Animated.View>

                    // render an absolutely positioned modal component over that background
                    <View style={styles.modalContent}>

                        <View key="text_container">
                            <Text>{this.state.text}?</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View key="options_container">
                            // keep in mind the content styling is very minimal for this example, you can put in your own component here or style and make it behave as you wish
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.state.callbackSubmit();
                                }}>
                                <Text>Confirm</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.state.callbackCancel();
                                }}>
                                <Text>Cancel</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View> 
        );
    }

    render() {
        return this.body()
    }
}

// to center the modal on your screen 
// top: metrics.DEVICE_HEIGHT/2 positions the top of the modal at the center of your screen
// however you wanna consider your modal's height and subtract half of that so that the 
// center of the modal is centered not the top, additionally for 'ios' taking into consideration
// the 20px top bunny ears offset hence - (Platform.OS == 'ios'? 120 : 100)
// where 100 is half of the modal's height of 200
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalBackground: {
        height: '100%', 
        width: '100%', 
        backgroundColor: 'gray', 
        zIndex: -1 
    },
    modalContent: { 
        position: 'absolute', 
        alignSelf: 'center', 
        zIndex: 1, 
        top: metrics.DEVICE_HEIGHT/2 - (Platform.OS == 'ios'? 120 : 100), 
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        display: 'flex', 
        height: 200, 
        width: '80%', 
        borderRadius: 27,
        backgroundColor: 'white', 
        opacity: 1 
    },
})
```

App.tsx render and import

```
import { ModalView } from './{your_path}/ModalComponent';

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} />
            <AppRouter />
            <ModalView />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

and to use it from any component

SomeComponent.tsx

```
import { _modalEmitter } from './{your_path}/ModalComponent'

// Some functions within your component

showModal(modalText, callbackOnSubmit, callbackOnClose) {
    _modalEmitter.emit(strings.modalOpen, { text: modalText, onSubmit: callbackOnSubmit.bind(this), onClose: callbackOnClose.bind(this) })
}

closeModal() {
    _modalEmitter.emit(strings.modalClose)
}
```

Hope I was able to help some of you, I used a very similar structure for in-app notifications

Happy coding