# how to make translucent buttons over a image in react-native using native-base?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, native-base

I was trying to make buttons as shown in the screenshot.but can't figure out how can i make them look translucent.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Content} from 'native-base';

export default class AppBody extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Content>

                <Image source={require('./img/bg3.jpg')} style={{ width: 360, height: 509 }}>




                </Image>
            </Content>
        );
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336569/how-to-set-background-color-of-view-transparent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background color of view transparent in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336569/how-to-set-background-color-of-view-transparent-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rgba value for the backgroundColoras follows:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)'
```

This sets it to a grey color with 80% opacity, which is derived from the opacity decimal, 0.8. This value can be anything from 0.0 to 1.0.

Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336569/how-to-set-background-color-of-view-transparent).