# How to put Background color with opacity into the full screen background image with Native-Base?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I've found lots of code examples about how to cover with the background color and add opacity into the full-screen image but don't know how to do it with Native-Base? Like in the Login screen there is a Background image. I would like to add some color to it with opacity so it will be changed like in photoshop. As you know in Native-Base everything must be inside  and  tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background color of view transparent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336569/how-to-set-background-color-of-view-transparent)

Comment: I tried it its not showing because it stays under the back ground image. While I need put it into the Background image