# How to add transparency to a value from a HTML input type color field in CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, transparency

In my CSS I need an color based on user picked color.
The color picked is used with a fixed transparency of 80%.

The following form element will let the user choose a color easily.

```
<input type=color value=#00ffff> // #00ffff
```

But how can I add transparency to it in CSS?

```
rgba(#00ffff,.8) // doesn't work
```

**Update**: I specifically asked how to do it in CSS, not in JS. BTW it's for a PHP driven CMS. I don't wanna force JS on users, and I prefer not to write conversion functions in PHP.

> Probably I have to wait for CSS4 (SASS/LESS like) color functions, or
>   for the input type color element to be enhanced with an hsla/rgba
>   pattern attribute functionality.

Comment: So, you want the user to pick a color and then apply it with 0.8 opacity to something. You can use the color normally and then add opacity:0.8; Or transform hex color to 3 decimal colors and use rgba.

Comment: Do you wish for the user to see a transparancy in the color?

Comment: here is a couple of answers
[convert-hex-to-rgba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646738/convert-hex-to-rgba)

Comment: thats not how you do rgba or rgb, you have a hexcode in your rgba. `background-color:rgba(192,192,192,0.3);` - that is rgba - http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_colors_legal.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb) ,First you need to convert hex value into `rgba`

Answer (score 7):

you can do it like this using jquery, you can apply a custom color with a custom transparency to an element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input").change(function() {

    var opacity = $("input[type=range]").val();
    var color = $("input[type=color]").val();

    var rgbaCol = 'rgba(' + parseInt(color.slice(-6, -4), 16) + ',' + parseInt(color.slice(-4, -2), 16) + ',' + parseInt(color.slice(-2), 16) + ',' + opacity + ')';

    $('div').css('background-color', rgbaCol)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=color value=#00ffff>
<!-- color -->
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1">
<!-- transparency -->

<div>this is a div</div>
```

Comment: Why Jquery? If you can do with the platform there's no need to load a library.

Comment: you mean that stackoverflow support jquery by default ? I did not understand you well @AndrewBone

Comment: Thx, this is a nice JS solution, I guess @Andrew wonders why you made jQuery a dependency and not used plain JS.

Answer (score 7):

Building upon @Abdelaziz Mokhnache's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40280985/18005234)

You can also create your own simple color input using pure javascript without having to load externally, like this:

```js
let color_picker=document.querySelector("#color_picker");
let color_wrapper=document.querySelector("#color_wrapper");
let color_picker_alpha=document.querySelector("#color_picker_alpha");

function set_color(el){
    color_wrapper.style.backgroundColor=color_picker.value + (color_picker_alpha.value == 255 ? "" : parseInt(color_picker_alpha.value).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"));
}
```

```css
#color_wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#color_wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: black solid 2px;
  border: white solid 3px;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  visibility: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#color_picker {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: initial;
  visibility: visible;
}


#color_picker_alpha {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id=color_wrapper>
  <input id="color_picker" oninput="set_color(this)" type="color" data-color="black">
  <input id="color_picker_alpha" oninput="set_color(this)" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

In CSS4 there is the [8 digits RGB hexadecimal](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notatio) notation: #RRGGBBAA.
Last two digits are the values for the alpha channel.

That makes it easy to concatenate the alpha value to the hex string.

Not sure about browser support at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this color but only knowing the HEX type, try convert it into RGB or HSL by using color picker tool, there r many online. Then just add alpha chanel ( 0 -1) for transparency. Eg. Rgb(225,10,10, 0.7)
Use this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
background-color : rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.8);
```

Refer this,

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/6-color.html

Comment: is it possible to use rgba values inside your `value="#ff00ff"` ?

Comment: `<input type="color" value="rgba(255, 5, 5, 0.5)">` clearly it's not.

Comment: What If user puts `#000` in input ?

Comment: The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color) is correct: "The value of an <input> element of type color is always a DOMString which contains a 7-character string specifying an RGB color in hexadecimal format. While you can input the color in either upper- or lower-case, it will be stored in lower-case form. The value is never in any other form, and is never empty."  Always the 6-digit value, never `rgba` or 3-digit or 8-digit (`rrggbbaa`).

Answer (score 0):

```
function rgbA(color) {    
    rgba=color.substring(0,7)+$('#AlphaFill')[0].value.padStart(2,'0').replace(100,'');
    return rgba;
}
```

insert an Input type="range". Send your 6 digit Hex to the above function.
rgbA('#ff0000')

`<input id="AlphaFill" class="range1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="100" />`

returns 8 digit rgba in HEX: range 80 = #ff000080 or range:0 = #ff000000 or range:100 = #ff0000

Answer (score 0):

The last 2 digits change the transparency

`#ffffff00` => min color opacity

`#ffffff83`

`#ffffffff` => max color opacity

**edit** : as [Lazerbeak12345](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6353323/lazerbeak12345) said input[type=color] alpha channel has been [requested](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/1422) but no progress yet.

Comment: `input[type=color]` doesn't support the alpha channel. (and has been [requested](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/1422) but no progress yet...)

Comment: oh it's weird i didn't notice that, cause i test before answering. thanks i edited my answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last two digits are also Hex, so 80 doesn't mean 80%, but more or less 50%

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding 'e6',

```
 $('#color').change(function(e){
    $('.mask').css('background-color', e.target.value+'e6')
    console.log(e.target.value+'e6')
})
```

Try using browser console and go to elements, find your target element and pick a color there, the last 2 characters in the color is the alpha... just in my experience

Answer (score -8):

Try this

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

This will display the transparent color for the user picked one.

Comment: This makes the entire element transparent. Not the color.