# transparency in html input type="color"

Tags: html

```html
<input type="color" />
```

A simple question, I see this simple color picker has only 3 versions `rgb, hex, hsl` but where is the option to choose transparency even in inspect element there is such an option

[image: inspect element's tool]

So what can I do? I even tried to make a default value of hex with a 00 in the start like changing `#ffffff` to `#00ffffff` so that it would be a transparent white, but it makes it just white

How to make `<inptue type="color" />` to have a transparency tool??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add transparency to a value from a HTML input type color field in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280110/how-to-add-transparency-to-a-value-from-a-html-input-type-color-field-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant seem to find a default HTML input with color that also uses transparency, but looking at the link Alex sent, using a secondary slider input seems to be the easiest method for user input. Here is a slider thats slide background matches whatever color is in the color input and the slider outputs a value between 0 and 1.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider"), color = document.getElementById("color");
color.oninput = function() {
    slider.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0),"+color.value+")";
    let rgb = hexToRgb(color.value);
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "rgba("+rgb.r+","+rgb.g+","+rgb.b+","+slider.value+")";
}
slider.oninput = function() {
    let rgb = hexToRgb(color.value);
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "rgba("+rgb.r+","+rgb.g+","+rgb.b+","+slider.value+")";
}
function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0),#00ffff);
  outline: none;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type=color value=#00ffff id="color">
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01" class="slider" id="slider">
<div id="test" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: This one is too difficult, I wanted something easy but as it seems there is no easy way so I am accepting this answer :)

Comment: If you need me to explain anythign about the code I'd be happy too, I trust you can intuitively piece it together though. Good luck with your project.