# jQuery convert hex to rgba

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, chart.js

I'm setting up a simple web chart using chart.js. Given a hexadecimal color value like `C8C8C8`, I want to get `rgba(200, 200, 200, x)`. The `x` is passed as a second variable. My code looks like this:

```
function colorconvert(color, transparency) {
        var r = parseInt(color.substring(0,2),16);
        var g = parseInt(color.substring(2,4),16);
        var b = parseInt(color.substring(4,6),16);
        var a = parseInt(transparency);
        return ('rgba(r, g, b, a)');
}
```

But Chrome dev console logs the error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse color from string "rgba(r, g, b, a)"

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can find solution here [convert hexa to rgba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646738/convert-hex-to-rgba)

Comment: Example here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return ('rgba(r, g, b, a)'); will return text

```
'rgba(r, g, b, a)'
```

You should return something like

```
return ('rgba(' + r ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ', ' + a + ')';
```

Comment: There were some parenthese and punctuation mistakes, but this worked: return ('rgba(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ', ' + a + ')'); Thanks a lot!