# JavaScript normalise CSS color values (convert to hex?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

`element.style.color` will be whatever the stylesheet specifies, `rgba(121, 110, 12, 14);`, or `rgb(...` or `hsl`, `#afd544` etc.

How can I convert `element.style.color` to some standard, comparable value (RGB-triple or hex string for example) using JavaScript?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646738/convert-hex-to-rgba

Comment: @majusebetter that's just a hex-to-rgba converter, I already know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('color')`.

Should give you the `color` property in the unified `rgb(r, g, b)` format.